# Why does one get a 0.000 Mann-Whitney U value (not p-value) etc.?

Tags: spss, post-hoc, multiple-comparisons, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

1) Is it okay to run a Mann-Whitney U test on unequal sample sizes i.e. two groups (N=11, N=12)or is there an alternative test?
2) What does it mean when one obtains a zero value for a Mann-Whitney U test (bearing in mind I obtained zero values before with equal sample sizes)

```
Ranks               
**Site    N   Mean Rank Sum of Ranks**
1         12    18.50     222.00
3         12     6.50      78.00
**Total   24**      



**Test Statistics** 


 Mann-Whitney U     .000
 Wilcoxon W       78.000
 Z  -4.157
 Asymp. Sig. (2-tailed) .000
 Exact Sig. [2*(1-tailed Sig.)] .000b
 Exact Sig. (2-tailed)  .000
 Exact Sig. (1-tailed)  .000
 Point Probability  .000

 a Grouping Variable: Site
 b Not corrected for ties.
```

Comment: A value of $0$ occurs when all the data in one group are strictly less than all those in the other group, that's all.  That suggests the normal approximation (to compute the P-value from Z) might be inaccurate.  Indeed, in the example shown, the exact two-tailed p-value is $2/\binom{24}{12}$, about 7.4E-7, while the normal approximation gives 3.2E-5, which is 44 times too large--but that's unlikely to change the conclusion that the medians are different.

Comment: @whuber Thanks so I can report (U=0, p<0.001), is that right?

Comment: Maybe: I see a footnote about "not corrected for ties."  You should look into that.